# SQLITE date offset

Tags: sqlite, dateadd

I am trying to replicate the following, which is written in some other flavor of SQL:

```
where contact_date <= open_date 
        and contact_date  >= dateadd(days, -30, open_date)
```

And below is my SQLITE query, I have replaced dateadd with SQLITE date analog, but not behaving as expected. I made sure the columns were 'DATE' type, but when I use the date function to make a 30 day offset, it just NULLs out the date.

Here is my query now:

```
SELECT Template, "Outcome Date" as contact_date,"Open Date" as open_date,
date("Open Date",'-30 day') window_date_start
--cast("Outcome Date" as integer) contact_date_int, cast("Open Date" as integer) open_date_int,
--strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', "Outcome Date") as contact_date_strft,   strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', "Open Date") as open_date_strft 
from Emails e
join Listing l
on l."Onovative Id" = e."Onovative Id"
where
contact_date <= open_date
--and contact_date > date(open_date,'-30 day');   <=== Not working
```

**Output**

```
Template    contact_date    open_date   window_date_start   <=== cannot really see below, but NULL
product offer loans auto runoff email   5/20/2020 11:02 6/19/2020 0:00  
onboarding digital banking email    5/22/2020 11:02 6/24/2020 0:00  
onboarding digital banking email    5/22/2020 11:02 5/5/2020 0:00   
product offer loans auto runoff email   5/22/2020 11:02 6/25/2020 0:00  
onboarding deposits checking 100 email  5/29/2020 11:06 9/24/2020 0:00  
onboarding deposits checking 100 email  5/29/2020 11:06 5/5/2020 0:00   
onboarding digital banking email    5/29/2020 11:06 9/9/2020 0:00   
onboarding digital banking email    5/29/2020 11:06 6/9/2020 0:00   
product offer loans auto runoff email   5/29/2020 15:12 9/30/2020 0:00
...
```

Anyone know how to offset dates in SQLITE?

Comment: In SQLite dates must have the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and datetimes `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: I created this with pandas dataframes and sqlalchemy - should I (in python) convert all my mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd before using sqlalchemy to make my_sqlite.db ?

Comment: And if the dates ARE in the correct format, `date( open_date, '30 days' )` will create the date 30 days after `open_date`. See [Date and Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more details.

Comment: I don't know about sqlalchemy, but SQLite date/time functions like date() work only with the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: thank you forpas, I will try and pre-format